# how to use single child scroll view properly

Tags: flutter

I used the Single child scroll view on my homepage which is I'm Implementing. but seems like it's not working. my page is not scrolling. Is there any other way to use the Single child scroll view or am I using it incorrectly? below I have mentioned my code for you to refer to. appreciate your help on this.  below is the error.

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6f4d1
> relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1982
> pos 12: 'hasSize'

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../constants/colors.dart';
import '../widgets/bottomNavigation.dart';

class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DashboardScreenState createState() => _DashboardScreenState();
}

class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
            child: Container(
              width: 30,
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/user.png',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
              child: Text(
                "Hi, NEO",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  //fontFamily: "Dubai"
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),

            // color boxes
            //box one
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  height: 115,
                  width: 115,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '0',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 30,
                            height: 30,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Colors.white24,
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.message,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),

                      // leads
                      Text(
                        'Total Leads',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                //box two
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  height: 115,
                  width: 115,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '0',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 30,
                            height: 30,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Colors.white24,
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.notifications_active,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),

                      // leads
                      Text(
                        'Unread Messages',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 13,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                //box three
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  height: 115,
                  width: 115,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                    color: Colors.teal,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '0',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 30,
                            height: 30,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Colors.white24,
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.star,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),

                      // leads
                      Text(
                        'Unresponded Reviews',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 13,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            // SizedBox(
            //   height: 30,
            // ),

            Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    "Your Leads",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      //fontFamily: "Dubai"
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  height: 75,
                  width: 350,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        offset: Offset(0, 1),
                        blurRadius: 5,
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: 30,
                            height: 30,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Colors.black26,
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.message,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Leads Received',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 13,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '0',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 100,
                            height: 5,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Colors.black26,
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  offset: Offset(0, 1),
                                  blurRadius: 5,
                                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  height: 75,
                  width: 350,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        offset: Offset(0, 1),
                        blurRadius: 5,
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: 30,
                            height: 30,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Color(0xff42E299),
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.done,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Accepted Leads',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 13,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '0',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 100,
                            height: 5,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Color(0xff42E299),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  offset: Offset(0, 1),
                                  blurRadius: 5,
                                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  height: 75,
                  width: 350,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xff42E299),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        offset: Offset(0, 1),
                        blurRadius: 5,
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: 40,
                            height: 40,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Colors.black26,
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.handyman_outlined,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 25,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 30,
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Keep it up!',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'You have completed 1 job',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 13,
                                  // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [

                Container(
                  height: 80,
                  width: 350,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        offset: Offset(0, 1),
                        blurRadius: 5,
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(child: BottomNavigation()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

//bottom navigation bar

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class BottomNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomNavigation> createState() => _BottomNavigationState();
}

class _BottomNavigationState extends State<BottomNavigation> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;


  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Home',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.business),
                label: 'Business',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.star),
                label: 'Reviews',
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
          ),
        ],
      ),


    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think removing the `singleChildScrollView` and convert the `Column` to `listView` widget may solve your problem. (it is really long widget tree. So insert only needed parts here)

Update: error is because of the expanded widget at the bottom. when you wrap a column with a `singleChildScrollView` widget the column becomes a `listview`, means it can has unlimited height. When you wrap a widget with a expanded widget, that widget will trying to get the remaining height space to it's child widget. In this case it is impossible because the column wrapped around a `singleChildScrollView` has unlimited height. So remove that widget or give a specific height to it.
[see the gif file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WDgeXR6avJc0IJGlZVxyp8jc53rVCO0X/view?usp=sharing)

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: const [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    "Hi, NEO",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      //fontFamily: "Dubai"
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

           .
           .
           .
           .
           .
          //put your other widgets here.
           .
           .
           .
           .
         
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 60,
            child: BottomNavigation(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.  RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout. getting this error after removing singlechildscroll view and renamed Column as List View

Comment: I have  removed expanded widget and wrap bottomNavigation in a container and gave a height. >>A RenderFlex overflowed by 94 pixels on the bottom.< still getting this kid or error. I think its because of a problem of Bottom Navigation. I have updated the   question with navigation bar code. please refer and kindly suggest me a way to correct this.

Comment: That may be because the given height for the container not enough. remove the singlechildscrollview and convert column to listview. then wrap that list view with a Expanded widget. to the body parameter create a column and give that expanded widget and bottomnavigation bar as che children

Comment: finally, it's working thank you so much for the kind support. appreciate ad good luck

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a height and width to `SingleChildScrollView`. This can be achieved by wrapping the Scroll View with a `Container` with specified height and width. If you  want to stretch the width,

```
Container(
  width : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
  height : 50 ///or any value
  child : SingleChildScrollView()
)
```